# Apache Spark UI doesn't work on public ip

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark

I'm new with apache spark .. I have a 8 cores ubuntu server with 24 GB of ram .. yesterday when i was running `$ ./spark-path/sbin/start-master.sh` it was starting cluster with ui on port 8080 and when I tried to access it from my desktop on chrome `server-ip:8080` it was working and i could access the dashboard .. but now it gives me `server-ip refused to connect` and when i curl from server `curl locahlost:8080` i could see the html content of dashboard . and net state shows me the runing ports

`$ netstat -nltp | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6485/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6164/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:6066          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6485/java`

so what i missed up guys .. and thanks ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay .. finally i couldn't solve it .. the problem spark starts master clustering on local ip .. so if you want it to open on public just add these lines

`SPARK_LOCAL_IP=SERVER_IP 
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=SERVER_IP`

to file 
`spartk-path/conf/spark-env.sh`

and run `$ ./spark-path/sbin/start-master.sh`

**Update**

or you can update your ~/.bashrc profile and add these lines

`export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=SERVER_IP
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=SERVER_IP`